# Windows apps open and then automatically get closed in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-installation, windows-store, windows-store-app

I have recently installed windows 8.1 professional on my pc. When I open windows store or windows store apps only the splash screen comes and then automatically the app gets closed. Sometimes a dialogue box comes that The app didn't start in the required time. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. First noticed it after installing the January 2015 Patch Tuesday updates. Have you found a solution?

Comment: In my case is worked by installing windows 8 first and then installing windows 8.1 pro original from the store for free. At first i was using the pirated. So i first installed a pirated windows 8 and then a legal windows 8.1 from store

Answer (score 0):

There are many [other users](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-winapps/windows-81-apps-close-immediately-after-opening/18849e15-4d6a-4474-a76a-bcf16013e9be) experiencing this problem too.
See [here](http://www.itworld.com/answers/topic/windows/question/metro-apps-crash-right-after-i-launch-them-what-can-i-do), [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ouc1too/archive/2014/07/22/windows-8-1-store-apps-won-t-open-or-close-immediately-when-logged-on-as-a-domain-user-make-it-stop.aspx) and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/winapps/metro-apps-crashing/a65b0e5a-b807-46a4-acec-ccc808821dd1).

> Check the following:
>
> 1. You need at least 1024X768 resolution for Metro(Windows Store) apps to work
> 2. Confirm if the issue reproduces with all user accounts. Metro apps aren’t supported if you are running with a built-in administrator
>      account (happens mostly when upgrading)
> 3. Check if UAC (User Account Control) is enabled. UAC must be enabled for Metro apps to work. It’s possible that a third party application
>      may have disabled the User Account Control, in which case the apps
>      won’t work. To check, simply type UAC from the home screen and it will
>      appear on the Settings search result
> 4. Try using a local account instead of a Microsoft Account (Live ID)
> 5. If you use an NVIDIA video card, follow the steps [here](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120407/workaround-for-windows-8-metro-apps-crashing-with-nvidia-beta-driver-for-dual-gpu-users/).

Also try this (worked for some users):

-Run **Command Prompt** as Administrator

-Type "**sfc /scannow**" (without quotes)

-Press **Enter** and wait (10/30 minutes)

-Restart your PC and everything should be ok

Still doesn't work? Follow the steps [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ouc1too/archive/2014/07/22/windows-8-1-store-apps-won-t-open-or-close-immediately-when-logged-on-as-a-domain-user-make-it-stop.aspx).

Comment: In my case is worked by installing windows 8 first and then installing  windows 8.1 pro original from the store for free. At first i was using the pirated. So i first installed a pirated windows 8 and then a legal windows 8.1 from store.